# Why will the Puma server not pickup changes to the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, puma-dev

I am running a local puma server for my rails app.

This is in my local_env.yml file

```
STAGING_URL: 'http://statrubytwotwo.test'
```

I can hit the URl when the server is running and all works fine. If I shut the server down with Cntrl-C and then hit the server it is still running.

To get the server to shutdown I have to do

`pkill -9 -f 'rb-fsevent|rails|spring|puma'`

The main problem is I change code. Do a `git add * --all` and a `git commit -m "something here"` and then start the server via `bundle exec puma`

The server starts up again, but the code changes are NOT seen. The puma server is running the old code?

UPDATE ====

I killed all with the following:

```
puma-dev -stop
pkill -9 -f 'rb-fsevent|rails|spring|puma'
pkill -USR1 puma-dev
```

I did a `rails s` and I see this

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.4 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: staging
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I hit the https://stattwotwo.test domain and it loads.

I hit http://localhost:3000 and NOT FOUND

I hit the https://stattwotwo.test domain and it loads

No matter what I do nothing ever loads on http://localhost:3000

I believe I recall the puma-dev will start anytime the domain is hit even if it is down (forman or pow)? Either way when it restarts it is not using new code.

Comment: I don't think that URL should work locally unless you're using something like pow/kapow/foreman/puma-dev. Are you running any other tools that might start the server?

Comment: puma-dev or foreman cannot remember which one.

Comment: I would probably puma-dev uninstall at this point, and remove it from the equation. There are one or two other tools out there that do that kind of loading, like invoker. Maybe you installed one a while ago and it's still running? What happens if you restart your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Adding as a response because I can't fit it all in a comment:

You need to find out which tool you're using. My guess would be puma-dev, and you installed it as a background process via [here](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev#background-installupgrading-for-port-80-access-os-x-only)

See if you can confirm.

Normally you'd get a conflict if there were 2 servers running, but that runs on a port other than the puma/rails default of 3000, which is what default `bundle exec puma` runs (I think?)

If that's the case, you've been starting a new server on a different port, while the old server (running your old cached code from when it started) is still running. That's why you don't see the changes.

You can confirm a couple things:

- Don't do `bundle exec puma`, do `rails s` and check the log to the screen and see if `:3000` is there
- Kill your puma like you've been, but visit your URL and see if it's still running
- Start `rails s` again, and visit `http://localhost:3000` and see if your code changes when you reload pages as you expect.
- Do `puma-dev -stop`, then `rails s`, and visit your .test url and see if it breaks (that means puma-dev was running in the background)

Comment: If I killed all with all three commands  see above in the post EDIT

Comment: You could also check for a tmp/pids file in Rails root. If it exists, it’ll tell you the pid of the currently running server.